# Get a DataSource/Connection from C3P0 connection pool

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am using a library where I need to get a data source and feed it into it. is there  anyway I can get a connection from a connection pool? I am using Hibernate 4 with C3p0 connection pool.

here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleDB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypass</property>

        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Shows Generated SQL Queries By Hibernate -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create The Database Schema on Start up -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="cache.provider.class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using hibernate and you want access to the c3p0 Connection pool it is already using , one easy approach would be to use the C3P0Registry class to find the DataSource, see [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_c3p0_registry_box) and [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/C3P0Registry.html).

Probably you will find that getPooledDataSources() returns a Set containing single element, and that will be the DataSource hibernate has constructed. If you want to, you can also set the config param c3p0.dataSourceName (hibernate.c3p0.dataSourceName in hibernate config), and use C3P0Registry.pooledDataSourcesByName( dataSourceName ).

[If you will set your own name, it would probably be worth verifying that hibernate is not using the dataSourceName property itself. I don't think that it does, but I haven't checked. The easiest way to check would be to look at your logs for the pools config dump on init, and make sure that there's something like "dataSourceName -> z8kflt8uqkl8iymaxxkw|729f44" in it. If the name is a long random-ish String with a pipe in it, it's an instance-specific autogenerated identity token and you should feel free to set your own name. If you see a more sensible name, then hibernate has already set this property and may be expecting the name you see, so you should look up that name.]

Note that if you plan to use Connections from the DataSource directly, take care to ensure that all Connections get properly close()ed in finally blocks. If you "leak" Connections, i.e. if you check them out and fail to check them back in reliably, you'll eventually exhaust the pool and freeze your hibernate app.

Good luck!

**Update:** Example...

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry;

// you probably want better Exception handling than this...
private DataSource findUniqueDataSource()
{
    Set set = C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources();
    int sz = set.size();
    if ( sz == 1 ) // yay, just one DataSource
      return (DataSource) set.iterator().next();
    else 
      throw new RuntimeException("No unique c3p0 DataSource, found:" + sz);
}

// be sure you have configured a dataSourceName in your c3p0 or hibernate config
private DataSource findDataSourceByName( String dataSourceName )
{ return C3P0Registry.pooledDataSourceByName(dataSourceName); }
```

And no, you should not "leak" Connections and expect the pool to clean up after you. You can forget to close Statements and ResultSets, and the pool will take care of them when you close() the Connection, but the pool doesn't know *when* it's safe to snatch a Connection back from a client that has failed to close it. Some applications hold Connections open for a long time (although that's bad practice, if you are using a Connection pool).

You can *force* c3p0 to clean up leaked Connections after a period of time, see the config parameter [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout). But this is an icky strategy; I recommend if you have a leak to use this in concert with [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces) only temporarily, to understand where you are leaking Connections and then fix the problem.

Comment: can you provide example on how to do this? also if I "leak" connection  I thought it will automatically close?

Comment: Thanks, though I am currently using this to setup my c3p0 connection, https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool where here can I set the dataSourceName? also what is the use of your findUniqueDataSource? why can I just directly use the findDataSourceByName?

Comment: i'm not positive, but probably <property name="c3p0.dataSourceName">appDataSource</property> will work for setting the dataSourceName param there. you'd use findUniqueDataSource if you haven't set a dataSourceName, because you cannot predict the autogenerated name.

Comment: Thanks for the information, if would/ help/added info, I updated my question to include my hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Btw how can I close the DataSource or return the DataSource to the pool?

Comment: you don't want to close() the DataSource yourself if it is already properly managed by hibernate. (hibernate will close he DataSource when your app closes its hibernate SessionFactory. but you do have to take care to close() every Connection you acquire from the DataSource.

Comment: so with your given code, once I get a dataSource. all I have to do is use that dataSource(pass it to an object) then leave it as it is?

Comment: yes, as long as your hibernate app is already managing the resource properly, you have nothing you need to do except use it.

Answer (score 0):

c3p0 provides connection pool for Hibernate, as **The built-in Hibernate connection pool is in no way intended for production use. It lacks several features found on any decent connection pool** - According to [Hibernate Community Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html), for configuration of c3p0 with Hibernate you can refer to [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool) or [MKYong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/) tutorial on Hibernate Community.

Comment: I already configured the my C3P0 connection pool using the first link, is there anyway I can get a connection/DataSource from a connection pool? since I am going to need it and pass it somewhere in my code.

Comment: @user962206 Did you find a way to get connection/DataSource ?